# Can I use the DT Package with the tabsetpanel function in RShiny?

Tags: r

I am attempting to build a simple shiny app that shows two different tables on different tabs. I've read quite a few similar issues on stackoverflow, but none have solved my issue so far.

Each time I run the app in rstudio I get the below error:

`Error in divTag$attribs : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Note: I don't get this error if I only display one table with the tablesetpanel.

Below is my code

```
dataframe1  <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  rime   point   sound
  Y      Y       Y
  N      N       Y
  Y      Y       Y
  NA     NA      NA
")

dataframe2  <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  rime   point   sound
  Y      Y       Y
  N      N       Y
  Y      Y       Y
  NA     NA      NA
")


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Standard Mastery Trackers"),

    tabsetPanel(type="tab",
        tabPanel('Kindergarten',
                 DT::DTOutput("dataframe1_table")),
        tabsetPanel('First Grade',
                    DT::DTOutput("dataframe2_table"))
        )
    )

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$dataframe1_table <- DT::renderDT({
        dataframe1
    })

    output$dataframe2_table <- DT::renderDT({
        dataframe2
    })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Don’t you have to explicitly tell shiny you want each datatable in each tab? I THINK your server side is fine. What if you put each datatable in your UI, in their own tabset and labeled them 1 and 2? And it looks like your error might be due to the fact the data frames aren’t reactive

Comment: You have Kindergarten as `tabPanel` but have First Grade as `tabsetPanel` - did you mean for the second to also be `tabPanel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code for a bit and it worked for me.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Standard Mastery Trackers"),
            tabsetPanel(
                id = 'dataset',
                tabPanel("Kindergarten", DT::dataTableOutput("region_kinder_sum")),
                tabPanel("First Grade", DT::dataTableOutput("region_first_sum")),
                tabPanel("Second Grade", DT::dataTableOutput("region_second_sum")),
                tabPanel("Third Grade", DT::dataTableOutput("region_third_sum"))
            )
        )

server <- function(input, output) {

    # choose columns to display
    output$region_kinder_sum <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(step_kinder_sum)
    })

    # sorted columns are colored now because CSS are attached to them
    output$region_first_sum <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(step_first_sum)
    })

    output$region_second_sum <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(step_second_sum)
    })

    output$region_third_sum <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(step_third_sum)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer so that others can see that your question is resolved